# VT-100 commands are working strangely

Tags: linux, nasm, system-calls, vt100

I'm writing simple clock program with NASM. I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 Vagrant box under OSX via iTerm. Terminal is xterm, so should be VT-100 compatible.

I need to remove one line. For instance, I expect the following behaviour:

```
Hello, this is clock program
13:01:25 UTC+4
```

Next moment:

```
Hello, this is clock program
13:01:26 UTC+4
```

I wrote the following functions. For print:

```
func_print:
  mov eax, sys_write
  mov ebx, stdout
  int 0x80
  ret
```

For clear:

```
clr          db 0x1b,  "[K"
clr_len      equ $-clr
...
func_clear:
  mov ecx, clr
  mov edx, clr_len
  call func_print
```

For saving and restoring positions I use VT-100 and its commands: `[7` and `[8` respectively:

```
csave db     0x1b, "[7"
csave_len    equ $-csave

crestore     db 0x1b, "[8"
crestore_len equ $-crestore
```

My code:

```
global  _start
  _start:
    mov ecx, welcome
    mov edx, welcome_len
    call func_print

    call func_print
    call func_save_cursor_pos

    mov dword [tv_sec], 2
    mov dword [tv_usec], 0

    call func_sleep
    call func_clear

    call func_restore_cursor_pos
    mov ecx, welcome
    mov edx, welcome_len
    call func_print

    jmp func_exit
```

However, the result is:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ./run.sh
Hello, this is the clock program
Hello, this is the clock program
Hello, this is the clock program
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$
```

If I change `clr` by adding `[1A` or `[1B` it seems to be removing lines to much higher than needed or lower:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ./run.sh
Hello, this is the clock program
Hello, this is the clock program








Hello, this is the clock program
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$
```

How can I fix it? What is the correct code?

Comment: Since you're only updating a single line, have you considered using `\r` instead?

Comment: This is just an example, I'd like to update any number of lines, actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your issue is related to the newline implied to be in `welcome db "Hello, this is the clock program", 10`. I can't tell for sure because you didn't post that part of your code.

I think that this causes an issue because the newline causes the terminal to scroll - when I removed the newline from my version, it worked properly. If you only need to update one line, it works to just not have a newline.

I suspect that the save and restore operations work on literal physical locations on the screen - not logical locations that get scrolled by newlines.

In general, however, I'd recommend using the cursor manipulation escape codes instead:

- When you're ready to redraw your output, write `db 0x1b, "[nA"` to move up n lines. (You'll need to put the number in there.)
- Immediately after that (or after any subsequent newline), write `db 0x1b, "[K"` to clear that line. (You already knew this, but I'm including it for completeness.)

I wrote an example program to implement this, based partially on yours. It displays:

```
Hello, this is the clock program.
Line two.
```

Then, a short while later

```
=== TEST ===
More.
```

And then

```
=== TEST 2 ===
Again.
```

This technique should be generalizable to any reasonable number of lines.

```
BITS 32
section .text

welcome      db "Hello, this is the clock program", 10, "Line two.", 10
welcome_len  equ $-welcome

test_str     db 0x1b, "[2A", 0x1b, "[K=== TEST ===", 10, 0x1b, "[KMore.", 10
test_len     equ $-test_str

test2_str     db 0x1b, "[2A", 0x1b, "[K=== TEST 2 ===", 10, 0x1b, "[KAgain.", 10
test2_len     equ $-test2_str

func_print:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    int 0x80
    ret

pause: ; Note: DON'T EVER USE THIS IN A REAL PROGRAM. This is not how you sleep properly.
    mov eax, 0
loop:
    inc eax
    cmp eax, 1000000000
    jl loop
    ret

global  _start
_start:
    mov ecx, welcome
    mov edx, welcome_len
    call func_print

    call pause

    mov ecx, test_str
    mov edx, test_len
    call func_print

    call pause

    mov ecx, test2_str
    mov edx, test2_len
    call func_print

    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80
```